# Select data based on the percentile

Tags: r

I'm trying to select 5 numbers from my data set based on the percentile

```r
dat<- c(1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9)
quant<- quantile(dat, prbs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))

 0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 1.0  4.0  6.0  8.5 11.0
```

There is no data corresponds to the 25% and 75% percentile. How can I select the number closest to the percentile instead?
The desired result is 1,5,6,9,11

Comment: Calculate the difference between your values and the 25th percentile, then filter for the smallest distance(s)

Comment: How can the largest value be 11 when 11 does not appear in dat?

Comment: I don't get the results you're showing us, I get `1    3    5    7    9`.  If you're really getting those results, please post `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type` argument to `quantile()` controls how it chooses results.  I don't know what your data really looks like but if I use

```
dat<- c(1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

I get the same results as you by default, and then types 1 to 3 all give

```
 quantile(dat, prbs=seq(0,1,by=0.25), type=1)
 # 0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 #  1    3    6    9   11
```

This meets your verbal question "How can I select the number closest to the percentile instead?"; you'll need to read the help page for more subtle differences.